# g++ variadic templates. Simple Sample code won't compile, complains 'Not a template'

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, variadic-templates

I'm poking around this unfamiliar territory, and thought I'd try a simple example from [Danny Kalev's tutorial on the matter](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=397).  The code is pretty simple:

```
template<> struct Count<> { static const int value = 0;};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
    struct Count<T, Args...> //partial specialization
{ 
    static const int value = 1 + Count<Args...>::value;
};
```

But gcc 4.4.7 and even 4.7.0 complain (despite -std=c++0x -std=gnu++0x flags) that:

```
/src/tests/VTemplates.h:12:8: error: 'Count' is not a template
/src/tests/VTemplates.h:12:18: error: explicit specialization of non-template 'Count'
/src/tests/VTemplates.h:16:8: error: 'Count' is not a template
/src/tests/VTemplates.h:16:26: error: 'Count' is not a template type
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template<> struct Count<> { static const int value = 0;};
```

is a template specialization with no template arguments. But you can't specialize a template class that is not already a non-specialized template.  In other words you must first establish a non-specialized version of the template class, and only then can you specialize it.  So for instance, if you did:

```
//non-specialized template
template<typename... Args>
struct Count;

//specialized version with no arguments
template<> struct Count<> { static const int value = 0;};

//another partial specialization
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct Count<T, Args...> 
{ 
    static const int value = 1 + Count<Args...>::value;
};
```

That would work.

Comment: Since it's not intended to be used, you should leave the non-specialized one defined: i.e. `struct Count;`

Comment: Well, yes, that would and does work.  Thank you for the clarification, which in retrospect is pretty obvious.  So obvious that the original author didn't think it needed to be included.